# why exception is a class and not a interface in java?

Tags: java

As we all know exception is a by default class and exception class extends `Throwable`.

My question is: why exception is not a interface ?

if we will try to mold exception class as interface it will show error. i tried it out but still i am not able to find a exact reason for the same. 
this is a code I tried:

Interface:

```
package com.prg;
import com.thed.util.CustomException ;
public interface ExceptionInterface extends Throwable{
     public String sayHello() throws CustomException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Class:

```
package com.prg;
import com.thed.util.CustomException ;
public class ExceptionCheck implements ExceptionInterface {
     public String sayHello() {
       return "Hey";
     }
     public ExceptionCheck() throws CustomException {
        System.out.println("hi");
     }
     public static void main (String[] args) throws CustomException {
       System.out.println("how are you");
         throw new ExceptionInterface({
           public String sayHello() {  return "Hey"; }
         });
     }          
  }
```

If i am changing interface to class then it is not showing exception which is expected. but why not interface this is my question ?

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: because there is *quite a lot* of **implementation** code to be found within the `Throwable` class which is the base of the whole hierarchy. And as one comment reminds us: there is also a lot of exception related code *backed* into the native parts of the JVM - and it would be probably very hard if that code had to deal with arbitrary objects implementing an Exception interface.

There is no point in using interfaces when you want to give a **core** library element to your users that includes **implementation**.

( keep in mind that default methods - aka method bodies - weren't allowed in Java until Java8 !)

Beyond that: *interfaces* are useful to allow different "views" on classes. In other words: Integer for example can be seen as *Comparable*. There might be situations where it is perfectly fine to *only* address an Integer object as a Comparable. But the true *essential* nature of Integer is still: it is a class representing a whole number of a certain range.

Now think about exceptions! What would be the conceptual "sense" in having `public class Foo implements Exception`? What would Foo be about "without" that exception view?! In other words: exceptions are also conceptually "important" enough to stand as distinct classes!

Keep in mind that classes and interfaces exist to model *abstractions*. Maybe I am just not creative enough - but I do not see how something could be a `Foo` object - but also, if required be an exception.

Finally: a class is a class, and an interface is an interface. Those are **different** things. And the only relation that is allowed is: classes extend classes, and can implement interfaces. Interfaces can only extend other interfaces. That is simply how the Java language is *designed* - and there is no way of doing what you code implies you want to do.

Comment: To me, the latter part of your reasoning is the most convincing.

Comment: @JiriTousek Sure. My brain seems to work like the java JIT - it needs a warmup phase. My answers often get better with each edit I do ;-)

Comment: For exceptions to work, you need some implementation that couldn't be done in pure Java, most notably getting your stack trace (ok, with Java 1.5 they gave us access to that via Thread.getStackTrace(), but the decision for a class instead of interface was made long before that).

Comment: Good point. I updated my answer a bit - but I am not sure "how much" of an argument that gives towards not having exceptions being pure interfaces.